# How to redirect the event messages of a built-in server displayed at the console to a file in a C program?

Tags: php, windows, redirect, localhost, stdout

**Overview**

I can successfully redirect the event log of a PHP built-in server on my PC through a command line.
I wish to do the same in a C program

**My environment**

- OS : Windows 7, Windows 10.
- Development language : C / C++.
- Web server software : PHP (version 7.4.8).

**Description**

When, on my PC, I open a built-in server with the following command line :

C:\PHP> `cmd /c phpstart.bat > C:\PHP\event.log 2>&1`

with the batch file *phpstart.bat* :   `php -S localhost:5000 -t C:\PHP\dev`
and the *index.php* file in the C:\PHP\dev folder, the events which appear on the console as standard output are redirected to the event.log file exactly the way I wish.

A sample of what I get in the event.log file looks like :

```
C:\PHP>php -S localhost:5000 -t C:\PHP\dev 
[Sun Jul 26 14:06:20 2020] PHP 7.4.8 Development Server (http://localhost:5000) started
[Sun Jul 26 14:06:35 2020] [::1]:20064 Accepted
[Sun Jul 26 14:06:35 2020] [::1]:20064 [200]: GET /index.php
[Sun Jul 26 14:06:35 2020] [::1]:20064 Closing
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Now, *I wish to do the same in a C program* : open the built-in server and redirect the events from the *stdout* to a log file.

I was thinking using a function such as **CreateProcess** (or other). In my C program, I can open the server with :

```
CreateProcess(NULL, "php -S localhost:5000 -t C:\\PHP\\dev", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInfo);
```

However, I can't see how to redirect the *stdout* to the file from here.

Obviously, getting CreateProcess followed by a   `> C:\PHP\event.log 2>&1` won't work since CreateProcess is a C function and not a Windows command.

**Installing PHP**

Those who wish to install the PHP web server software the way I did can follow the instructions from this page :
https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-install-php-on-windows/

Could someone point me towards the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works, but have you tried writing the stdout to a file directly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  while(running){
    myfile << stdout; 
  }
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Alternative in C (probably needs some tweaking):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w+");//remember that this only works if the directory exists already
   while(running){
        fprintf(stdout);//maybe missing a linebreak, but not sure.
   }
   fclose(fp);
 }
```

Comment: How would you translate the above code (C++) into C ?

Comment: changed it. use stdio.h and fopen / fprintf / fclose methods